# how to solve to build ionic 3 with firebase issue

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

ran build without fail yesterday but suddenly firebase issue has occurred. what should i set for this issue?

i tried the following

`cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9`
`cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0`
`cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0`
`cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.2`

link:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_may_31_2019

but that shows that

- What went wrong:
  The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[18.0.0,18.0.0]], but resolves to 19.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

so i changed messaging version that

`cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0`

but also shows error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
  Failed to execute aapt

  `ionic cordova build android`
  `ionic cordova run android`

I did what firebase shows me to do, but it hasn't been resolved.

thanks

Comment: Same problem with this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1081

In particular @dpa99c's comment
https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1081#issuecomment-503135862

I was having the same problem since the Firebase support update (June 17, 2019) but running through those steps in @dpa99c's comment worked for me.

In addition to this, if you are building for iOS as well then you may need to update to the latest version and install pod inside your iOS platform folder if you haven't done so already.